# Splitting a list into uneven sub-lists

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to split a list of 50 items into different sized sub-lists; e.g. 3 of 10, 4 of 5.

I tried doing this using `take` but this just takes the first few items in the list repeatedly rather than moving along by index.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this? Or can link me to a Prelude/Data.List function which may aid me. (I have looked around but I am struggling to find anything.)

Comment: [splitAt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt).

Comment: [`splitPlaces`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitPlaces)

Comment: splitPlaces seems to be perfect. I'm using it in a later function. Any idea how I would access each sublist individually when assigning them?

Answer (score 1):

A fitting combination of

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

and

```
snd :: (a, b) -> b
```

should do the trick.

EDIT:

```
splitUp :: [Int] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitUp [] xs = [xs]
splitUp _ [] = []
splitUp (l:ls) xs = let (a,b) = splitAt l xs in a : splitUp ls b
```

Comment: I understand how this would work for the first sublist; and the last. But how exactly would I use this to get the items at indexes 10-20?